# Add Native Ads to Flutter, IOS project

Tags: ios, flutter, admob, native-ads

i have a problem with native ads in flutter ios project i followed this documentation

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter?hl=fr#7

but i have this problem when i running the app

note : the banner is working fine and the native is working fine in android [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxpJS.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please make sure that your using test ad unit for Native Ad which is `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511`